# Not getting desired result using join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried left,right,inner join here is my tables

SHOP_OFFER_STATUS

```
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | MOBILE_NUM            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | SHOP_ID               | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | OFFER_ID              | int(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | OFFER_STATUS          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | OFFER_GENERATED_ID    | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
    | OFFER_GENERATED_DATE  | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
    | OFFER_EXPIRY_DATE     | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | OFFER_CODE            | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | AMOUNT                | decimal(9,2) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | BILL_AMOUNT           | decimal(9,2) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

TRACK_TRANSACTIONS

```
    +------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
    +------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | TRANSACTION_ID   | int(255)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
    | TRANCTION_TYPE   | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
    | TRANSACTION_DATE | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
    | AMOUNT           | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    | MOBILE_NUM       | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    | SHOP_ID          | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    +------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

i know its my design problem and i have thousands of records(can't rollback or redesign),here how it works when ever person redeems the offer in transaction table shop_id and mobile_num will be added I am trying to get BILL_AMOUNT,TRANSACTION_DATE from this tables...but its giving wrong result...i want to know when(TRANSACTION_DATE ) and what amount he redeemed!

TRANSACTION table have many other transactions like usercreated,commented etc(TRANCTION_TYPE) and offer redemption are around TRANCTION_TYPE='MERCHANT CASHBACK' 100 records  if i join this tables more then 50 thousands records comes in :( here is the query!

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM TRACK_TRANSACTIONS T RIGHT JOIN
      SHOP_OFFER_STATUS S
      ON T.SHOP_ID=S.SHOP_ID
 WHERE T.TRANCTION_TYPE='MERCHANT CASHBACK' AND S.OFFER_STATUS='REDEEMED';
```

the desired output:100 records where offer redemption happend!

Comment: This question is pretty unclear of what you want and what would be the desired result.

Comment: what we want is a little more clarity

Comment: @Drew plz see edited question!

Comment: You are not joining on the primary key, so it is not surprising that you are getting more records than you expect.  I would suggest that you edit your question with some sample data and desired results. A SQL Fiddle is also very helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff exactly Gordon thats the design mistake i have done..any alternative plz help :)